# Telegram Bot node js - Как получить Id юзера

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot

В общем задача такая: мне нужно выдавать юзеру его же айди в сообщении. Как это можно реализовать?

Использую node-telegram-bot-api. Пробовал вот так:

```
var idforuser = bot.user_id;

bot.on('message', (msg) => {
if (msg.text.toLowerCase() === "мой айди"){
bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, "Это твой айди - " + idforuser, menu)
}
});
```

Но при исполнение выдает: "Вот твой айди - undefined".

Answer (score 0):

```
bot.on('message', (msg) => {
    var user_id = msg.from.id;
    if (msg.text.toLowerCase() === "мой айди"){
        bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, "Это твой айди - " + user_id);
    }
});
```